# Statement Invalid Error while running Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unit-testing

I have a model `friend_request` and wrote unit tests for this model. While running tests, I get this error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block                                       
:SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"friend_requests"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Any idea what is wrong?

`Edit :`

I ran this query :

```
 bundle exec ruby -I test test/models/friend_request_test.rb -n test_should_validate_name
```

Comment: show your original query.. Only error is not useful.

Comment: Well.. I meant to show the code where you wrote the query..

Comment: The problem is that after running this test, rails doesn't even enter my test function. It throws this error before running that test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` solved my problem. The database wasn't created in my test environment.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have shown is not the one that is causing your problem.

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

This means that you have started a transaction, and then had an error. After that every command you attempt will give you the above error: it will not accept any more commands until you roll back the transaction.

Look backward through your log file into you find the original error to diagnose your problem. If you cavity find it in the application log file, you may find it in the postgresql log file.

Sometimes this kind of scenario can be caused by incorrect error handling. For example if you had a subroutine which started a transaction, then gave some commands but did not check for errors, you might have left the database handle in an errored state.

Comment: I am not that familiar with rails, bit that does not sound like the right approach. You need to know what caused the original problem. Look back through the logs.

Comment: My test command would have started a transaction and got an error. Any idea how can I see what caused the error

Comment: As stated in my answer, the error would be visible in the postgresql log file. BTW is it possible that a test prior to the one you are looking at has caused the error? Is there was an errored transaction before your test even started?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Everything ran fine before running this test.

Comment: Deleting friend_requests.yml fixes the problem. Any idea what's wrong?